# Is there a connection between Medea and Len?

Tags: fate-stay-night, nasuverse, carnival-phantasm

in *Carnival Phantasm* when everyone is in Ahnenerbe we see Medea (*Fate/Stay Night* Caster) and Souichirou Kuzuki. but there is someone else with them

[image: Medea, Kuzuki and Len]

Medea has a girl on her lap and i know that girl is Len, the Succubus Demon Familiar who travelled with Arcueid Brunestud before she made a contract with Tohno Shiki in *Kagetsu Tohya*

[image: Len]

Looking at them in this shot we see that they sorta look similar. similar hair and similar ears. but to my understanding in *Carnival Phantasm* Medea and Len never interacted with one another, yet here they are with Medea looking sorta motherly with Len in her lap.

Is there some sort of connection between Medea and Len which would indicate why 2 are like this in Ahnenerbe when they haven't interacted in the series?

Comment: I'm not sure it's anything more than they look like mother and daughter.

Comment: A Greek witch picks up a cat succubus. Cats and witches go hand in hand.

Comment: Medea is a bit of an otaku as you know and Ren is a cute loli. She's gonna take her home.

Answer (score 1):

Medea loves the idea of being domestic according to Hollow Ataraxia.

*If* someone gives her full control and she respects them, she basically goes full wife.

The joke is simply that she's just mothering Ren who is like a child.  And Ren isn't the type of person to be bothered by it.